# I am trying to pass a matrix to a function to change it but i know i have to use pointers just don t know how

Tags: c, matrix

thats my code  i try to change it for hours but can t come with something that works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

void init_board(char board[7][7]){
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            board[i][j]='.';
        }
    }
    board[3][3]='o';
    board[4][4]='o';
    board[3][4]='x';
    board[4][3]='x';
}

int main(){
    char board[7][7];
    char *Board;
    init_board(&board);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            printf("%c",board[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
return 0;

}
```

i am using gcc as compiler
i would like some help with pointers and how can i solve my problem
the code in the function work out of the function but inside i can't ,ake it work because of the pointers

Comment: Remove `char *Board`, change `init_board(&board)` to `init_board(board)`, and put the `printf("\n");` **after** the `j` loop. But note that none of those are preventing the code from working. The second one should be giving you a warning, so you need to fix it. And as for pointers, your function is already using pointers, because arrays are always passed as pointers.

Comment: thanks my problem was that i was trying to call the function the wrong way thanks for the help, i was exploding my head.

Comment: You are also accessing outside of the bounds of the array, `i<8` should be `i<7`.

Comment: thanks i also saw that after because now i am making a function to print the array so i saw that the array doens need to be 7 and need to be 8 so i got it right , thanks for the help and the reminder.